# How to use echo twice to populate data from php to html client using ajax

Tags: php

I am trying to use echo in php for populating data twice as per user different action using ajax.
But it seems that I am unable to use echo twice to populate data from php server to my html page.
here is the code for php:

```
<?php   

// Receive the Data from Client
$data = $_REQUEST;
$fileName = $data['fileList'];

$files = glob( "*.txt");

//it will pass data while the html page load (and working fine)
echo json_encode($files);

//set the file path for text files

$file_Content = file_get_contents("temp.text");
//this will pass while user click a button, but while using it is not working, even the first echo also
echo json_encode($file_Content);
?>
```

Is there any way to do it? or any suggestion pleas..Thanks

Comment: You need to send an AJAX parameter to test `isset()` against in PHP, for different actions.

Comment: I suggest you combine the two data and echo it in the last part like `json_encode(array($files,$file_Content))`.

Comment: What you describe is  not expected behaviour. Can you try reproducing your error? You could use something like https://3v4l.org/

Comment: It looks like you just need one AJAX request, so do what `@MarkVincentManjac` says. Just know that you will have an array with two elements that you get data from within the AJAX success method, coming from the argument. Note that you should have at least one `isset()` in PHP usually, so the PHP code won't be run, unless data was sent.

Answer (score 0):

To form and respond with a valid json object, you can only call json_encode once. You're currently responding with two encoded json objects, which is invalid, so I'm guessing only the first one is being interpreted.

Remove the first json_encode echo, and encode an array of both properties in your second (now only) echo. I've taken the liberty to guess at what might be sensical properties for your response object here:

```
echo json_encode(['files' => $files, 'content' => $file_Content]);
```